# Spring boot - Add custom MongoDB Converter

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, jersey, converters

I've searched over and over and none of the solutions found worked for me or maybe I'm just too noob because I've just started working with Spring.

I'm using Jersey with Spring boot.

I have the following domain classes:

```
@Document(collection = "Videos")
@Getter @ToString @Builder
public class Video {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String titulo;
    private String url;
    private String miniatura;
}


@Document(collection = "Categorias")
@Getter() 
@ToString
public class Categoria {
    private String nombre;
    private Video[] videos;
}
```

Now, I have documents like this in my DB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b56e9fbb8a2f4ec7805c73e"),
    "nombre" : "Tus dudas de salud",
    "videos" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b56e556b8a2f4ec7805c52b"), 
        ObjectId("5b56e556b8a2f4ec7805c52b"), 
        ObjectId("5b56e556b8a2f4ec7805c52b")
    ]
}
```

My repositories are just empty because I only need to do `.findAll()` at the moment:

```
package es.sanitas.hos.portalpaciente.repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import es.sanitas.hos.portalpaciente.service.vo.Categoria;

@Repository
public interface CategoriasRepository extends MongoRepository<Categoria, String> {
}
```

And my configuration for Mongo is in an `application.yml` file:

```
spring:

data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/test
```

My pom.xml incase it's useful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>es.sanitas.hos</groupId>
    <artifactId>PortalPacienteRSHQ</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now the problem is that when I try to get the `Categorias` from the DB. It gives me an exception saying that `no converter found capable of converting String to Video`.

I understand that this is because the data is retrieved from the DB as a string with JSON like format and it's not capable of assigning it to the `Video` attribute from `Categoria`.

I'm not able to make any of the Converters examples to work from other questions.

Can someone give me hand on how to successfully implement a covnerter so I can do stuff with the video string?

Thanks.